# Excel VBA: For Each loop for Long Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with a few VBA For Each loops in my Excel workbook, and for some reason I get a run-time error after my loop reaches the 32,766 row. I figured this was an Int/Long type error, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Here's my current code:

```
' Add Play Call hyperlinks
Dim Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim FileName As String
Dim Bureau As String
Dim CopiedFilesDirectory As String
Dim AudioFilePath As String

lastRow = Sheets("CallLog").Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Sheets("CallLog").Range("I" & firstRow & ":I" & lastRow)

For Each Cell In Rng

    FileName = Range("I" & Cell.Row).Value
    MatterNumber = Replace(Range("K" & Cell.Row).Value, "/", "-")
    ContactUsername = Range("M" & Cell.Row).Value
    Bureau = Range("N" & Cell.Row).Value

    CopiedFilesDirectory = ImportCallsUserForm.CopyFilesDirectoryTextBox.Value
    AudioFilePath = CopiedFilesDirectory & Bureau & "\" & ContactUsername & "\" & MatterNumber & "\" & FileName & ".flac"

    With Worksheets("CallLog")
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("S" & Cell.Row), _
            Address:=AudioFilePath, _
            ScreenTip:="Click to play call", _
            TextToDisplay:="Play Call"
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("T" & Cell.Row), _
            Address:="", _
            ScreenTip:="Click to write a summary", _
            TextToDisplay:="Write Call Summary"
    End With

Next Cell
```

Since I'm working with ranges, I thought that maybe there was a special type of variable for Int Ranges vs. Long Ranges, but I couldn't find anything after doing extensive online research.

Any assistance is always appreciated, and I'm happy to help clarify anything that isn't clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are facing has nothing to do with the Range or iterating through it. It's due to the limitations of the number of Hyperlink fields you can add into a worksheet. The limitation is around 65530. Since you add two hyperlinks per iteration, you are maxing out at 32766.

You could work around this by having a worksheet_click event fire some code that uses the target.range to dynamically create a URL, like this loop is doing, and send the user there. That's not a great workaround, but it's the best you can do given the limitations of Excel.

Comment: That makes so much sense as I've been racking my brain for hours trying to figure this out. So my spreadsheet is a call log of sorts, where each row represents one phone call. One of the two hyperlinks serves as a way to listen to the audio file, the other launches a separate macro userform. I might just use the 65,530 links for the 'Play call' link, and then come up with some sort of code to insert macro buttons on every row to launch the userform. Why does this limit exist?

Comment: Instead of the Macro buttons, I would highly suggest using the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick()` event. You can use that by double clicking the worksheet in the VB/Macro Editor. Then using the drop downs at the top of the area where you write the code, choose "Worksheet", and "BeforeDoubleClick". The variable `Target` will hold the range/cell that was double clicked by the user. You could format your URL using that and open it in whatever program.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared `firstRow` or `lastRow` anywhere. These will likely be interpreted as Integer Variants when they are first used.

Declare these explicitly as `Long`, and you should be fine.

It's a good idea to also use `Option Explicit` at the top of every module - this forces you to explicitly declare all variables, so errors of this type cannot occur.

Comment: I have, just not in this code snipit. I really do appreciate the input, @citizenkong.